# What is the gradient of a matrix functional?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Given matrices $B$ and $C$, define the functional

$$f (A) := \|ABA^T-C\|_F^2$$

All matrices are $n \times n$ and $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. What is the gradient of $f$ with respect to $A$?

I calculated it as $\nabla_A f(A)=(ABA^T-C)AB$, but I'm not sure if it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(A) = ABA^T -C$, then $Dg(A)H = ABH^T+HBA^T$.

Let $h(A) = \|A\|_F^2$, if the space is real then $Dh(A)H = 2 \langle A, H \rangle$.

Since $f = h \circ g$ we have

$Df(A) = Dh(g(A)) ( Dg(A)H) = 2 \langle ABA^T -C, ABH^T+HBA^T \rangle$

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
Df(A) &=& 2 \operatorname{tr} ((AB^TA^T-C^T) (ABH^T+HBA^T)) \\
&=& \langle 2(AB^TA^TAB+ABA^TAB^T-C^TAB-CAB^T), H \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

*Alternative approach*

Let us define the Frobenius product by a colon, for brevity, i.e.,
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C \right) := A: BC
\end{align}

We will use the cyclic property of trace, e.g.,
\begin{align}
A: BCD = B^T A: CD = B^TAD^T: C
\end{align}

Let us rewrite your function in terms of Frobenius product for simplicity,
\begin{align}
f(A) 
&= \left\| ABA^T - C \right\|_F^2 \\
&\equiv ABA^T - C : ABA^T - C
\end{align}

To find the gradient $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$, we compute the differential and then obtain the gradient
\begin{align}
df(A) 
&=  2  \left(ABA^T - C \right) : d(ABA^T) \\
&= 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right): \left( dA BA^T + ABdA^T\right)\\
&= 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right):  dA BA^T + 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right): ABdA^T \\
&= 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right) \left( BA^T \right)^T :  dA  + 2 \left(  AB \right)^T \left( ABA^T - C \right): dA^T \\
&= 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right) AB^T :  dA  + 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right)^T \left(  AB \right): dA 
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f(A)}{\partial A}
&= 2 \left( ABA^T - C \right) AB^T + 2 \left( AB^TA^T - C^T \right) AB
\end{align}

You can simplify further if you prefer. I hope this helps